# Authenticate the firebase private database using rest api

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Generated the token [Using this file for authentication](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/auth/exampletokengenerator).
After that, I generated a rest url by reading this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token)

> I hit from my terminal curl "https://sampleproject-763e9.firebaseio.com/USERS.json/?auth=my generated token from above file".
>   For the generation of my token, I used these two things:

- Enter User ID:userM1
- My Jason which I got from firebase by going into project settings->serviceaccounts->adminsdk and clicking **generate new private key**.

I got this error

> { "error" : "Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header: '5e3994c7ce7839ecbe22b9c01e0cc0e1db2593b1' with iat: '1505402027'" }.

This is how my database looks like[image: My databse is]

These are the rules for my private database.[image]My output.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This not the way to get authentication to firebase secret database.
After generating the token from json you have to generate access token by signing in.